# SQL Order By DESC and ASC gives same order

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to sort the results by most recent datetime in SQLite.
After a bit of trying i got

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
ORDER BY strftime(Date, '%Y'), strftime(Date, '%m'), strftime(Date, '%d') DESC
```

This gives me the Orders sorted from oldest to newest, so of course changing the DESC to ASC should give me what I want, but it gives me the exact same order...

What is going on here?

Solution (@forpas):
Change format to YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm
Thanks alot everyone!

Comment: @HoneyBadger That doesn't seem to change anything... If i only sort by date, it sorts by month but starts at first of month. Thank you!

Comment: What is the format of the column Date?

Comment: @forpas dd.mm.YYYY HH:MM

Comment: Change the format to `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM` and sort simply by Date ASC or DESC. SQLite's date functions like strftime() return null with any other text date format.

Comment: @forpas that seems to have done it, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `SORT BY Date DESC` ???
I understand there is not DATE type in SQlite, but if your stored you dates in any of the 3 provided ways, it should work without transformation.

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
> Applications can choose to store dates and times in any of these
> formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
> time functions.

Comment: When i try to just order by date, it sorts by month, then day starting at 1 instead of 31, so i would get (for example) 03.03, 06.03, 14.03, 04.02, 07.02 but i want 14.3, 06.03, 03.03, 07.02, 04.02

Comment: Obviously (and as @forpas found out) because you Date field is badly filled, not following the rules above. "shit in, shit out"...